# How to cancel UITableview reloaddata function in iphone

Tags: iphone

In my application, I have pushed from oneviewcontroller to anotherviewcontroller. In that page I have started a timer and updated `UITableview` for every 1 sec (using `UITableview reloaddata`).

I have start the timer in `viewwillappear` function and invalidate timer in `viewwilldisappear`.

But when timer is running, when I came back to my viewcontroller my application crashed rapidly.

Please help me? Thanks in advance...

My guess is when i push back to viewcontroller that time tablereloads in previous viewcontroller that time it make crashes. I am using try catch but nothing makes any difference. Can we stop tableview reloads when we are not in that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason of your app crashing is that, when-ever u come back form anotherViewController to oneViewController, your table view got release in between your timer still alive which is trying to update tableView and when you accessing the release object then app will get crashed. So u need to before stop your timer properly and nil it if timer isValid.
I hope mine answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You strongly need to send *invalidate* message to all you timers at dealloc method of your class

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    if ([_someTimer isValid]) [_someTimer invalidate];

}
```

Comment: Invalidating the timer in dealloc is pointless.  As per docs here (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#jumpTo_4) the NSTimer holds a strong reference to target until it is invalidated.  As a result, your object will never reach dealloc until the timer it holds is invalidated.